# Is there a way to log that someone has made a CSRF attack to a web-application

Tags: csrf-protection

I understand how CSRF works, why it works & how to mitigate it. now, I have a web-application, its vulnerable to CSRF, I want to know if someone has successfully made a CSRF attack on my web-app. Is there a way to log it if there's CSRF

Thanks 
Suzee

Answer (score 0):

As a long as your app is not secure itself there is no better chance than going through the logs and see if there were requests with a referrer from an unknown site/site that makes not much sense. But this only works, when all the request headers are logged.

Once your app is secure, somewhere will be code like this

```rb
if is_csrf_attack
  log_csrf_attack
else
  go_on
end
```

**Edit**: With "making not much sense" I meant that you should look for URLs in referrer headers that should not send requests to your site -> it makes not much sense for these sites to call your API/URLs.

Comment: Exact response I've been looking for. Thanks very much. but I wonder Why did you say, it doesn't make much sense

Comment: I answered your question in an edit. I should have probably used a comment but I am still new to SO. Check mark would be appreciated ;)